# Creating customized Pipeline Label in GoCD pipeline

Tags: pipeline, go-cd

I want to add the branch name which I have pointed in my Materials section in GoCD pipeline.

Currently, my pipeline label has the count and commits hash.

For example:

if my branch name is "master" 
the label should be 104-master-82862b9a99599130e0306429882ead4c22d07ce4

if my branch name is "US73173" 
the label should be 104-US73173-82862b9a99599130e0306429882ead4c22d07ce4

Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this by:

1. Creating a pipeline parameter in the Parameters tab to specify your git branch. ex: name: `mybranch` value: `US73173`
2. Using the new pipeline parameter to specify your branch instead of directly specifying it for the material in the Materials tab ex: `#{mybranch}`
3. Edit the label template on the pipeline in the General Options tab to use the new pipeline parameter.
   For example: `${COUNT}-#{mybranch}-${git}`

Go-CD Labels: https://docs.gocd.org/current/configuration/admin_use_custom_pipeline_label.html